# Turning a variable into a class object, via an imported function

Tags: class, python-3.x, global-variables

I have made a class definition...

```
class Element():
def __init__(self, word_list, type):

    self.type = type
    self.list = word_list
```

And on another Python file (practice_page_1) a function definition...

```
from class_element import Element

test_list = []

def test(word_list):
    num = 0
    for letter in word_list:
        if letter == 'd':
            global test_list
            test_list = word_list[:num + 1]
            test_list = Element(test_list, 'letters')
            return True
        num += 1
```

And then on another Python file the operation of the function...

```
from practice_page_1 import test
from practice_page_1 import test_list

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'g']
test(my_list)
print(test_list)
```

When it prints test_list it prints an empty list [] while I was expecting it to print a class object. However if I move the exact same lines of operation back to practice_page_1, it does print test_list as a class object. Why is this?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `from ... import ...`, the imported object is put in the current namespace.  It is a reference to the object itself, not the module variable.  If you want to get the most recent changes, use this:

```
import practice_page_1

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'g']
practice_page_1.test(my_list)
print(practice_page_1.test_list)
```

That works because you are now accessing the variable called `test` in the module namespace instead of the current one (which used to be the same object as that in the module namespace).  You probably want to do `import ... as ...` when you have a module with that long a name, but there you go.